# What did homogeneous coordinates allow 19th century mathematicians to do?

Tags: geometry, math-history, coordinate-systems, applications

I read about Mobius developing Barycentric and homogeneous coordinates, and I read about homogeneous coordinates and what they are and I'm totally on board with taking a line from the origin and seeing where it intersects with a given plane (e.g. the Z=1 plane) and that I can use that point to define the line and vice-versa.

I'm told this was really helpful to the mathematicians of 1830 onwards, but I can't find out why. So why was it so useful? Were there specific problems they were working on that suddenly became much easier? What could they do with homogeneous coordinates that they couldn't do before, apart from classifying lines by their point of intersection with a plane?

Comment: For starters, [projective spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space) (space taken under homogeneous coordinates) and the [Grassmannian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) (a generalization of projective spaces) feature heavily in algebraic topology and geometry.

Comment: So was that one of the problems mathematicians of the day were struggling with? They were saying to each other "How can we have a projective space and will we ever have a Grassmannian?"

Comment: Not quite. However, there are old questions in algebraic topology/geometry with relatively recent answers that use projective spaces and grassmannians as a helpful tool.

Comment: Okay; so that's us, now (or at least, much later than 1830 or so), finding really good uses for it. At the time, was it just something interesting but not really very helpful?

Comment: I couldn't tell you if the tool or the problem it was used for came first. I would guess that a problem came up that was solved using these as tools. Afterwards, people realized these spaces are interesting and useful, so more people learned about them and made/solved some more problems. That's how it usually happens, anyway.

Comment: Hi this is a little late, but I am asking questions about homogeneous coordinates too. I have found the books Worlds out of Nothing, by Gray and Geometry and its History, by Ostermann and Warner to be helpful.

In partial answer to your question it seems that there were (at least) 2 geometric schools of thought: those who used coordinates, and those who didn't. Projective geometry was first talked about in the latter. Thus coordinates put projective geometry into the first camp. 
To what end? It was suggested that geometry without coordinates was less rigorous. I don't know! But I'd like to